# Easy way to execute shell script

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, spotlight

I want to be able to search in Spotlight for a shell script (or something that calls a shell script) and that such shell script opens a Terminal window so the output is shown live (and I can interrupt with <kbd>ctrl + C</kbd>).

Right now, I have a `backup.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
caffeinate -s \
  rsync -hva --progress --stats --delete "/path/to/source/" "/path/to/destination"
```

that I've renamed to `backup.command` so I can doubleclick in Finder and it works perfectly. But I cannot search for it in Spolight because I want Spotlight to only search for Applications, System Preferences and Contacts, and if I mark Developer then it shows `backup.command` but also a lot of unwanted files that are just unnecessary.

### What can I do?

I tried to [appify](https://gist.github.com/mathiasbynens/674099) it but then it runs on the background, and doesn't open a new Terminal window so I can't see the progress of how is it going, and also I can't stop the progress with <kbd>ctrl + C</kbd>. Any suggestion?

Comment: maybe this is possible: appify an script, which opens a terminal and execute your script inside this terminal.

Comment: You can exclude directories containing unwanted **Developer** files from beeing shown in Spotlight. You can do it in Spotlight -> Privacy (You can drag folders from finder there also).

Comment: @hirnwunde That would be great, but I don't know how.

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek I would like to exclude *everything*.

Comment: Is there some good reason why you can't just call it `backup`, place it in the `$PATH` and just call it from a Terminal by typing `backup` and press Enter?  Also why not just use Time Machine, it seems it would be much easier then all you've been going through to get this to work.

Comment: @user3439894 I don't really care where to put it or what name to use, but what I want to avoid is opening the Terminal to call the script. Also, I don't need Time Machine since this is a script to duplicate the contents of a thumb drive into another thumb drive (in fact I don't *want* Time Machine, plus I think it doesn't work for that).

Comment: Yes Time Machine would not work on that and I thought you were backing up from internal to external not external to external, sorry.  Anyway, so you don't want to call it from Terminal, then place it on the Dock or the Desktop then you don't need to use Spotlight.  Although I know you're going got say you don't want to place it in the Dock or on the Desktop, so without enabling Development in Spotlight, then klanomath's answer is probably the best solution to use Spotlight without enabling Development in Spotlight.

Comment: See this from superuser: https://superuser.com/questions/221964/make-shell-script-executable-in-mac-os-x-without-entering-the-terminal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Appifying with Platypus:**

Download [Platypus](http://www.sveinbjorn.org/platypus) and create an app from the shell script.

Example:

[image]

The settings above create an app with a progress bar (including details) and it can be quitted - the rsync process has to be canceled (killed) manually though.

[image]

The app itself can be found with Spotlight.

---

**Simple AppleScript solution:**

In Mavericks (and probably later) you have to allow the AppleScript app to control the computer in "System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Accessibility"

Open ScriptEditor, enter the code snippet below and export it as an application with a unique name:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    delay 2
    set newWindow to do script "caffeinate -s rsync -hva --progress --stats --delete /path/to/folder /path/to/folder2"
    activate
end tell
```

If you need root permissions prepend *sudo* -> "sudo caffeinate -s ...."

You can refine the AppleScript app by checking if Terminal already has open windows and create a new one to run the shell script:

```
set myScript to "caffeinate -s rsync -hva --progress --stats --delete /path/to/folder /path/to/folder2"
tell application "System Events"
    if exists (window 1 of process "Terminal") then
        tell application "Terminal"
            set newWindow to do script myScript
            activate
        end tell
    else
        tell application "Terminal"
            delay 2
            set Window1 to do script myScript
            activate
        end tell
    end if
end tell
```

The AppleScript app can be found with Spotlight.

---

In Mountain Lion you have to enable "System Preferences -> Accessibility -> Enable access for assistive device" and change it a little bit to get the AppleScript app solutions running properly:

```
set myScript to "caffeinate -s rsync -hva --progress --stats --delete /path/to/folder /path/to/folder2"
tell application "System Events"
    if exists (window 1 of process "Terminal") then
        tell application "Terminal"
            reopen
            activate
            set newWindow to do script myScript
        end tell
    else
        tell application "Terminal"
            reopen
            activate
            do script myScript in window 1
        end tell
    end if
end tell
```

---

**AppleScript with "external" shell script (backup.sh):**

This is the final approach the OP is using. Taken from [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/121495/34487). In Mavericks (and probably later) you have to allow the AppleScript app to control the computer in "System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Accessibility". One can load the full `.sh` (placed inside the app in `Contents/Resources/backup.sh`) with:

```
set bashFile to path to resource "backup.sh"
tell application "Terminal"
    delay 1
    activate
    set newWindow to do script "bash " & quoted form of (POSIX path of bashFile)
end tell
```

You can refine the AppleScript app by checking if Terminal already has open windows and create a new one to run the shell script:

```
set bashFile to path to resource "backup.sh"
tell application "System Events"
    if exists (window 1 of process "Terminal") then
        tell application "Terminal"
            delay 1
            set newWindow to do script "bash " & quoted form of (POSIX path of bashFile)
            activate
        end tell
    else
        tell application "Terminal"
            delay 2
            set Window1 to do script "bash " & quoted form of (POSIX path of bashFile)
            activate
        end tell
    end if
end tell
```

Comment: No easy way to do this without any extra app?

Comment: @Manuel With your rigid Spotlight prefs I don't see any other possibility. An AppleScript app is the other possibility.

Comment: The “rigid prefs” is logic, I don't need anything else, and I don't want to spam my searches just because I want to be able to launch `backup.sh` or `backup.command`. In any case, how would that AppleScript solution work?

Comment: I added `activate` to bring the Terminal window to the front.  If that's not okay, then of course you can delete it.

Comment: @klanomath I will try the AppleScript with the help of this [question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/121495/34487), and come back ;)

Comment: @klanomath The script gave me `error -25211` when Terminal was open but [I solved it with the help of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140334/applescript-system-events-error-access-for-assistive-devices-is-disabled). In any case, if Terminal is not running two windows are opened when script is run. I'm running Mountain Lion.

Comment: @Manuel Hmm it doesn't work for me but you can edit in yourself: please add an addendum like: in Mountain Lion replace the lines xyz of the script with the content blublublu by blablabla

Answer (score -1):

Run `chmod 755 NameOfYourScript` from terminal, then `./NameOfYourScript`

If you `ls` it will appear green

Comment: I want to avoid opening from terminal.

Comment: @Manuel its called a shell script for a reason, that will definitely be the easiest way

Comment: I think it's called a shell script because it's written in shell. Sometimes you want to run things  from the shell, sometimes you want to run them from the gui.